# How are `postcss-import` configured plugins applied

Tags: css, webpack, postcss

I've just started using PostCSS exclusively with Webpack. When using `postcss-import` to inline external stylesheets, I see it's options allow us to configure plugins and transformers to be applied on imported sources, but I'm a bit confused on how this fits in together with other options configured for the main PostCSS runner.

For instance, if I want to inline URLs, should I be adding the `postcss-url` plugin to `postcss-import`, the PostCSS runner or both (if my main stylesheet also has URL references)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's recommended to make `postcss-import` the first plugin in your list when you're defining the plugins for postcss in webpack. Since `postcss-import` just inlines the `@import` to the start of the file, any postcss plugin defined afterwards will be applied to it.

Example:

(For the example i'm gonna assume you use a `postcss.config.js` file, the same logic applies if you use an array for the plugins in the webpack 1 format)

```
// Header.css
@import 'button.css';

.foo {
    font-size: 3rem;
    transform:translateY(-10px);
}

// Button.css

.bar {
   transform:translateX(20px);
}
```

If the import plugin is behind autoprefixer, it will first apply the autoprefixer plugin on the file and then afterwards import the `@import` file. So by the time the file is imported the prefixing will have already happened, the output will be:

```
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'autoprefixer': {},
    'postcss-import': {}
  },
};

// output.css
.bar {
    transform: translateX(20px); // Prefixing hasn't happened on the imported file
}
.foo {
    font-size: 3rem;
    transform:translateY(-10px);
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-10px); // original file has been prefixed though
}
```

If you put the import first though, it will inline the imported file and then do the autoprefixing, this means both the imported and the original file will be autoprefixed:

```
// postcss.config.js
    module.exports = {
      plugins: {
        'postcss-import': {},
        'autoprefixer': {}
      },
    };

// output.css
.bar {
    transform: translateX(20px);
    -webkit-transform:translateX(20px); // Also prefixed now

}
.foo {
    font-size: 3rem;
    transform:translateY(-10px);
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-10px); 
}
```

So this means you don't actually have to add plugins again in the option of the `postcss-import` plugin.